# raise forms.ValidationError not working

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, inline-formset

I have the following models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length="100")

    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    budget = models.IntegerField()

class Milestone(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length="50")

    budget_percentage = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

In the creation form for a Project, i've included an inline formset for milestones.

I want to validate that when a Project is subbmitted, at least 4 milestones are created, also that the budget_percentage of all milestones sums up to 100

This is my form:

```
class BaseMilestoneProjectFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def clean(self):

        if any(self.errors):
            # Don't bother validating the forms unless each form is valid on its own
            return

        if len(self.forms) < REQUIRED_MILESTONES:
            raise forms.ValidationError("At least %s milestones need to be created" % REQUIRED_MILESTONES)

        # Set initial control variables
        # Total percentage of budget to control
        total_percentage = 0
        # Date to control that milestones are linear, i.e. that second milestone isn't delivered before first
        current_control_date = date.min

        for i, form in zip(range(len(self.forms)), self.forms):

            if i == 0 and form.budget_percentage > MAX_BUDGET_FIRST_MILESTONE:
                raise forms.ValidationError("First milestone budget must not exceed %s percentage" % MAX_BUDGET_FIRST_MILESTONE)
            elif form.budget_percentage > MAX_BUDGET_MILESTONE:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Milestone's budget must not exceed %s percentage" % MAX_BUDGET_MILESTONE)

            if form.estimated_delivery_date < current_control_date:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Milestones must be linear, check your delivery dates")

            # Set control variables for next iteration    
            current_control_date = form.estimated_delivery_date                
            total_percentage += form.budget_percentage

        if total_percentage != 100:
            raise forms.ValidationError("All milestones budget percentage should sum up to 100%")
```

When I submit the form with 3 empty milestones forms it doesn't do nothing about the first
    forms.ValidationError(...)

I've verified with raise Exception() that in fact it enters the if, but it continues as if nothing happens.

It's an error in my code or a misunderstood concept of ValidationError?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I'm adding the view code that was missing

```
class DelayedModelFormMixin(ModelFormMixin):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.prepare_object_for_save(self.object)
        self.object.save()
        if hasattr(self.object, "save_m2m"):
            self.object.save_m2m()
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)

    def prepare_object_for_save(self, obj):
        pass

class ProjectNew(CreateView, DelayedModelFormMixin):
    model = Project
    success_url = '/projects/project/%(slug)s'
    form_class = ProjectForm

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProjectNew, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def prepare_object_for_save(self, obj):
        obj.owner = self.request.user
        # Code for stacked milestones and rewards
        context = self.get_context_data()
        milestone_form = context['milestone_formset']
        reward_form = context['reward_formset']
        if milestone_form.is_valid() and reward_form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            milestone_form.instance = self.object
            milestone_form.save()
            reward_form.instance = self.object
            reward_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectNew, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['milestone_formset'] = MilestoneFormSet(self.request.POST)
            context['reward_formset'] = RewardFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['milestone_formset'] = MilestoneFormSet()
            context['reward_formset'] = RewardFormSet()
        return context
```

Comment: What happens when you check if the formset is valid?    formset.is_valid()     It should return false.

Comment: How are you actually **using** the form?

Comment: Give us some clue on how you are using the formset. If you can, add the code of the view in which you are using the formset. Try to change the `len(self.forms)` part for [`self.total_form_count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#total-form-count-and-initial-form-count). [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) may help you

Comment: When you say "When I submit the form without 3 empty milestones forms", did you mean "When I submit the form WITH 3 empty milestones forms"? is "with" or "without"?

Comment: @mtnpaul i'm going to try that

Comment: @ThomasOrozco what do you mean with **using** the form?

Comment: i've added the view code, also, as @marianobianchi said, it is with not without (fixed now)

Comment: Sorry again but: did you forget to use `BaseMilestoneProjectFormSet` in the view? Or it is just a copy-paste naming-issue in your question? Is `BaseMilestoneProjectFormSet` the same as `MilestoneFormSet`?

Comment: I think you have a problem in your code. `prepare_object_for_save` returns (if everything goes fine) an `HttpResponseRedirect` but then you never use it. Besides, i think that http response doesn't have nothing to do in form_valid method (directly or not, as in this case)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "When I submit the form with 3 empty milestones forms it doesn't do nothing about the first forms.ValidationError(...)"?

Comment: @marianobianchi MilestoneFormSet inherits from BaseMilestoneProjectFormSet, that was a copy-paste issue. about the exception, the problem is that at the end it redirects to the success page, instead of showing any errors. I will think about the prepare_object_for_save

Comment: I've edited my previous answer @Santiago. Did you have a look at it again? May be the problem is where you are looking to the error. Give `non_form_errors` method a chance. You have to put it in your template to show formset errors.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question the problem is that you are counting how many forms are inside the formset, but you want/need to count how many [BOUND](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms) forms are in the formset.

So, i think you need to change this line:

```
if len(self.forms) < REQUIRED_MILESTONES:
```

for these lines:

```
bounded_forms = filter(lambda form:form.isbound(), self.forms)
if len(bounded_forms) < REQUIRED_MILESTONES:
```

then you can raise the validation error as you are doing it.

**Edit:**

Maybe you are not understanding how formset validation works. May be [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) can help, specially this phrase:

> The formset clean method is called after all the Form.clean methods have been called. The errors will be found using the non_form_errors() method on the formset.

If i understand what you mean when you say

> When I submit the form with 3 empty milestones forms it doesn't do nothing about the first forms.ValidationError(...)

then, you are not seeing the raised errors. So, the place to look for them is the formset "non_form_errors" method. Put something like this in your template:

```
<span>{{milestone_formset.non_form_errors}}</span>
```

Now you should see the errors you are raising in milestone formset clean method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, i've tested if it was entering the if with a raise Execption(message) and it raised the exception properly. The problem is with the forms.ValueError

Comment: I'm using the non_form_errors on my form template. The problem is that django acts as if nothing is wrong, redirecting to the success page, instead of going back to the form template